# Create SFTP Local User to Azure storage account using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-runbook

I'm using Runbooks and wanted to utilize a PowerShell script to establish an SFTP local user for an Azure Storage Account. I found an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=powershell) that has all steps but this is using the [Az.Storage 4.1.2-Preview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/4.1.2-preview). but I am using the latest version of the [Az.Storage](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/4.5.0) which is 4.5.0

Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support-how-to?tabs=powershell

In the above article, we are using the "**New-AzStorageLocalUserPermissionScope**" command but this is not available in the latest version of Az.Storage Module.

Did any face this issue earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked in the latest preview version [Az.Storage 4.4.2-preview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/4.4.2-preview) and the SFTP commands are present in the latest preview.

I would assume that this is due to the SFTP Storage account functionality still being in public preview. When the service is made generally available the `Az.Storage` module would be updated with the new commands!

You could have both versions installed in the automation account and implicitly specify the preview version for the runbook to create users:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-import-using-a-fully-qualified-name

Comment: I think I agree with you. SFTP feature is in preview mode.